# How to combine two conditions on to a foreach loop so it won't overlap with eachother?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

These two lines of code specifically - ($teamproject as $teamproject) and ($cattypes as $teamproject). Basically it's an image card that displays the catergory (cattypes) and the main image and the title of that specific image card.

```
<div class="container" id="projectcards">
    <div class="row">
     <?php     

if(!empty($error)){
        echo $error;
        }
 if (!empty($teamproject)) {  
 foreach ($teamproject as $teamproject): ?>

        <a href="/project-single/1" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnailx">
            <?php foreach ($cattypes as $teamproject): ?>
            <h4 class="post-content"><?=  h($teamproject->cattype_title)?></h4>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <img src="<?=  h($teamproject->mainimg)?>">
            <h3><?=  h($teamproject->title)?></h3>
        </a>

     <?php 
    endforeach; 
        } 
    ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how foreach works in PHP. The first item should be the name of an array, which it will iterate over, and the second what you want to call each item. This statement:

```
foreach ($teamproject as $teamproject):
```

Shouldn't list the same variable twice.

If it's just a single entity, don't iterate over it at all, just directly access its values.

If it's an array containing a list of teamproject entities, then just give the item a unique name for the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($teamproject as $project)
```

The second nested foreach- if this is supposed to be a list of headers for each specific team project, then it probably should be a list inside the single $project entity? As you have it written, it's just iterating over $cattypes array, and on each iteration, printing the same  $project title over and over again.

If cattypes is supposed to be a list on each $project, then its something vaguely along the lines of:

```
foreach($project->cattypes as $cattype)
```

Replacing "cattypes" with what ever that list is actually called on your teamproject entity.

Comment: I understand but is there a way to combine the two foreach statements together rather than keeping it seperated like shown on the example?

Comment: I'd need to see your controller code and table code to be more specific, but possibly

Comment: Got it sorted, Thanks. I had to add an IF condition inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding to foreach conditions, I had to add an IF conditions to get it working.

```
<div class="container" id="projectcards">
    <div class="row">
        <?php     
        if (!empty($teamproject)) {  
        foreach ($teamproject as $team): ?>

        <a href="/projects-single/<?=  h($team->id)?>" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnailx">
            <?php foreach ($cattypes as $cattype): 
                if ($team->cattype_id == $cattype->id ) {                            
                ?>
                <h4 class="post-content"><?=  h($cattype->title)?></h4>
                <?php  
            }  endforeach; ?>

            <img src="<?=  h($team->mainimg)?>">
            <h3><?=  h($team->title)?></h3>
        </a>
        <?php 
        endforeach; 
    } 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, if teamproject has a cattype_id, just list it as an association in the Table class, and in find call add a contain https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain

Comment: Yea understood. Thank you very much.